# Magento configurable product with Multiple select option, not drop down

Tags: magento-1.9, php, product-attribute, color-swatches

I have configurable products list in category page. Here there is option of color swatch. In Magento, by default, there is no option of multiple select of color attribute during color attribute creation for configurable product. But my client's requirement is that it will be color swatches and it will also be multyple select (max 4). The reference site is http://www.shoreprojects.com/collections/gift-box. I need the functionality, StepI, StepII, And StepIII in magento 1.9 like the reference site. I can't understand how to solve this requirement. I have googled by searching configurable product with attribute (color=>multiple select option). But there is no helpful result.If any one know about this type of requirement, then reply me or give a clue by which I will be helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

That does not make sense with configurable products as implemented by Magento. For each possible combination of attributes you have to create a simple product as stock keeping unit. Now imagine how many possible combinations you get with your scenario.

If you really need it like that (one sku per combination), create four configurable attributes color1, color2, color3, color4, and use them.

If not, you are looking for simple products with custom options instead.

Comment: I will have to do like this reference site, http://www.shoreprojects.com/collections/gift-box. It is my client's requirement. There is option of color swatch and multiple select in this reference site. I can't understand how to solve this requirement. I have googled a lot, but there is no fruitful result.

Comment: That can be achieved with a bundle product. Watch, strap and gift box are actually separate products that get combined to a bundle product. With bundle products you can have multi-select options.

Comment: But for color swatches, is it possible to change the color in bundle product, if I create a bundle product combined separate Watch, strap and gift box simple product. If yes, the how???? Will I have to do a customize??If yes, what will I have to do for that???

Comment: Question marks are not pack animals

Comment: And yes it's possible but you need to customize the frontend with your own JavaScript, this is not a core feature